# How many ways can we use to ask others' major?

Tags: grammaticality

As is showed in the title. I know:
  What is your major?
  What do you study for your bachelor's/ master's？
  Are there any other ways we can use to ask others' major?

Comment: In UK we ask "what are you reading?" No such thing as the noun major here outside of the army rank, only an adjective.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Could you tell me your major?"

"What are you studying?"

"My major is Major. What's yours?"

"What are you majoring in?"

"Your major is?"

"We've been talking all this time and I don't even know what your major is yet!"

"Hey, I'm Name." "Hi Name, I'm Name." "Major?"

"What major are you?"

Comment: "This is a holdup! Tell me your major, or the little dog on the counter gets it."

Comment: Also a good option and very versatile! Depending on the context, you'll either get a laugh or a begging to "Don't shoot, please!"